swiftuiにて、録音した音声をトリミングして出力しようとするときにエラーが出てしまう
背景
swiftuiを用いて、録音アプリを作成しています。その中で、録音した音声（ローカル保存）をトリミングする機能を実装しようとしています。
--5/13追記--
Xcode: Ver. 15.3
iOS: 17.4
発生している問題
trimAudio関数を作成し、実際にトリミングを実行しようとすると、以下のエラー文が出てきてしまい、うまく行きません。
error: Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "操作を完了できませんでした" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x301924ab0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16979 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=原因不明のエラーが起きました（-16979）, NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4149B4DE-458E-447B-B30E-EDD4EC82EE42/Documents/2024%E5%B9%B45%E6%9C%8812%E6%97%A5%20%E6%97%A5%E6%9B%9C%E6%97%A5%2020:21, NSLocalizedDescription=操作を完了できませんでした})

やったこと
現状のコードは以下の通りになります。エラーが発生しているのは、trimAudio()です。その他の部分は、録音を実施するために必要な関数になります。
（一部分を抜粋しております）
import Foundation

struct Recording: Equatable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var fileURL: URL //　ファイル保存先
    var audioTime: TimeInterval // 録音時間
    ...
}

import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI
import Speech
import CoreLocation
import UserNotifications

class AudioRecorderManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    // ==== 変数定義 ====
    var audioRecorderManager: AVAudioRecorder?
    var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine?
    var audioSession: AVAudioSession?

    @Published var recordings = [Recording]() //録音したファイルを格納する配列
    @Published var isRecording: Bool = false
    @Published var currentTimeDisplay: (minute: String, second: String) = ("00", "00")
    @Published var scrollOffset: CGFloat = 0

    // 初期化
    override init() {
        super.init()
        audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
        setupRecorder()
    }

    private func setupRecorder() {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        // 日付入力のための設定
        let f = DateFormatter()
        f.timeStyle = .short
        f.dateStyle = .full
        //        f.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
        let now = Date()
        
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            
            let documentPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let audioFilename = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("\(f.string(from: now))")
            
            let settings = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
            ]
            
            audioRecorderManager = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorderManager?.prepareToRecord()
        } catch {
            print("録音の準備に失敗しました: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    // 録音開始メソッド
    private func startAudioRecording() {
        do {
            try audioEngine?.start()
            audioRecorderManager?.delegate = self
            audioRecorderManager?.record()
            print("録音開始")
        } catch {
            print("録音の開始に失敗しました")
        }
    }
    
    // 録音停止メソッド
    func stopAudioRecording() {
        let audioTime = audioRecorderManager?.currentTime ?? 0
        audioRecorderManager?.stop()
        isRecording = false
        audioEngine?.stop()
        audioEngine?.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        
        if let recordingURL = audioRecorderManager?.url, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: recordingURL.path) {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: recordingURL)
                
                // 関係する引数のみ抜粋
                let recording = Recording(fileURL: recordingURL, audioTime: audioTime, ...)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.recordings.append(recording)
                }
                
                // ファイルのパスとサイズを出力
                print("録音が停止しました。ファイル: \(recordingURL.lastPathComponent), サイズ: \(data.count) bytes, 録音時間: \(recording.audioTime)")
                
            } catch {
                print("録音データの読み込みに失敗しました: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            print("録音ファイルのURLが取得できませんでした、またはファイルが存在しません。")
        }
        
        // audioRecorderManagerをリセット
        audioRecorderManager = nil
    }

    // ====音声編集メソッド====
    func trimAudio(
        at recordingURL: URL,
        audioTime: TimeInterval
    ) {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL
        let outputURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("trimmed-audio.m4a")
        
        print("outputURL: \(outputURL)")
        
        //ファイル削除
        _ = try? fileManager.removeItem(at: outputURL)
        
        // 出力用URLを設定
        //        let outputURL = URL(string: "Construct the URL for the trimmed audio file")
        //        let outputURL = recording.fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString + ".m4a")
        
        // トリミング開始時間、終了時間の設定
        let startTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(1), timescale: Int32(10))
        let endTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(audioTime - 1.0), timescale: Int32(10))
        // 開始時間、終了時間からtrimするTimeRangeを作成
        let exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: startTime, end: endTime)
                
        // AssetにInputとなるファイルURLをセット
        let asset = AVAsset(url: recordingURL)
        
        // m4aファイルとしてExport
        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) else {
            print("Could not create AVAssetExportSession")
            return
        }
        exporter.canPerformMultiplePassesOverSourceMediaData = true
        exporter.outputURL = outputURL
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a
        exporter.timeRange = exportTimeRange
        
        
        // Export
        exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            switch exporter.status {
            case .completed:
                print("Trim Success! URL -> \(String(describing: outputURL))")
            case .failed:
                print("error: \(String(describing: exporter.error))")
            case.cancelled:
                print("error: \(String(describing: exporter.error))")
            default:
                print("Unexpected export status: \(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                
            }
        })
    }



以下のURLを参考にしてコードを修正しました。outputURLの表現方法をいくつか試してみましたが、全て同じエラー文が表示されました。
https://qiita.com/rh_/items/e00d0492e13c176f369a
https://medium.com/@abdulrafy.ios345/efficient-audio-trimming-in-swift-a-comprehensive-guide-using-avfoundation-and-a-structured-ca27d718def2
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/112982
対処法について、ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

開発環境および実行環境のOSやIDEのバージョンについて記載してください。なお、DateFormatter.string()メソッドでDateオブジェクトを文字列化してAVAudioRecorderのファイル名に使おうとしているようですが、ファイル名にコロン:が含まれているとトラブルの原因になるのでやめたほうがいいです。URL.appendingPathComponent()ではパーセントエンコーディングしてくれません。

syghさん、ありがとうございます！
ファイル名をuuidに変更したら、エラーがなくなりました！

コメントに記載いただいた方法で解決しました！
具体的には、AVAudioRecorderのファイル名に日付を使わないようにしました。
おそらくご指摘のとおり : が入らないようにした結果解決したのだと思われます。
ありがとうございました！
